# ArrayList iterator not working when declared in loop

Tags: java

Why is the first snip running in an endless loop while the second works?

```
//Initial code
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("A");
myList.add("B");
myList.add("C");
myList.add("D");
myList.add("E");
while(myList.iterator().hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(myList.iterator().next());
}
System.out.println();



//Correct code
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("A");
myList.add("B");
myList.add("C");
myList.add("D");
myList.add("E");
Iterator itr = myList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Don't use iterators if you only want to process each element. Iterable classes are meant to be used in [for-each] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version of the code a **new** instance of the `Iterator` is created during each iteration of the loop, because the `ArrayList#iterator()` method is invoked.  Calling `iterator()` will return a new `Iterator` instance each time.  I suspect you may be thinking `iterator()` works similar to a Java beans `getXXXX` accessor, however it does not.

```
//new Iterator Instance will always have a next item
//Iterator is a different instance during each iteration
while(myList.iterator().hasNext()) { 
    System.out.println(myList.iterator().next());
}
System.out.println();
```

The second version of the code assigns the `Iterator` to a variable, which causes the `hasNext()` method to be invoked on the same `Iterator` instance.  Since this iterator instance has its `.next()` method invoked for each loop iteration it performs as you would expect and eventually ends the loop when `hasNext` returns false.

```
//Same instance of the iterator for each iteration
Iterator itr = myList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

**In a nutshell**

```
Iterator itr = myList.iterator();
Iterator itr2 = myList.iterator();
System.out.println(itr == itr2 ? "Same":"Different"); //outputs Different
```

It may also help you to see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29) for `ArrayList#iterator`:

```
 //notice how a new instance of the Nested Itr class is created
 public Iterator<E> iterator() {
     return new Itr(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

Every time you call `iterator()` you get a **new** `Iterator` with its cursor at the first element. You're consuming the first element, but discarding the `Iterator`. You're just not moving forward.